# How to map a sql query result to mutiple object in Mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to know how to map a sql query result to multiple object and how to set type of a function in dao. and in controller, how can I use Multple object mapped ??
for detail, I want to combined two object (Theater Object,Movie Object) for mapping the sql query.

mapping.xml

```
<resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="vo.theater.Theater">     
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="MovieBaseResultMap" type="vo.movie.Movie">   
</resultMap>

<select id="getLocalPlayingmovieTimeList" parameterType="vo.theater.Theater" resultMap="">      
</select>
```

dao.java

```
 public type getLocalPlayingmovieTimeList(Theater teater);
```

in controllor.java, how can I use Multple object mapped?
I want to get List type because the query result is a timeTableList